Cannot run facenet or machine learning in react native

This my code for AttendanceScreen, when I run it I get the error error detecting face: [typeerror: network request failed] error error confirming photo: [typeerror: network request failed]

import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Button, StyleSheet, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Camera, useCameraDevice } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import { fetch, decodeJpeg } from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

const AbsensiScreen = () => {
  const [cameraPermission, setCameraPermission] = useState(null);
  const device = useCameraDevice('front');
  const camera = useRef<Camera>(null);
  const [capturedPhoto, setCapturedPhoto] = useState(null);
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);

  const checkCameraPermission = async () => {
    const permission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
    setCameraPermission(permission === 'authorized');
    const status = Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus();
    console.log('Camera permission status:', status);

    if (status === 'granted') {
      setCameraPermission(true);
    } else {
      setCameraPermission(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkCameraPermission();
  }, []);

  if (cameraPermission === null) {
    return <Text>Checking camera permission...</Text>;
  } else if (!cameraPermission) {
    return <Text>Camera permission not granted</Text>;
  }

  if (!device) {
    return <Text>No camera device available</Text>;
  }

  const takePhoto = async () => {
    try {
      if (!camera.current) {
        console.error('Camera reference not available.');
        return;
      }

      const photo = await camera.current.takePhoto();
      setCapturedPhoto(photo.path);
      setShowPreview(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error capturing photo:', error);
    }
  };

  async function loadBackend() {
    await tf.ready();
    return tf.getBackend();
  }

  const loadFaceNetModel = async () => {
    loadBackend()
    const modelUrl = require('../assets/model/model.json');
    const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl);
    return model;
  };

  const detectFace = async (photoPath) => {
    try {
      const imageData = await fetch(`file://${photoPath}`, {}, { isBinary: true }).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
      const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(new Uint8Array(imageData));

      const model = await loadFaceNetModel();
      const embeddings = model.predict(imageTensor.expandDims(0));
      return embeddings;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error detecting face:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  const loadKnownFaces = async () => {
    const folderPath = `${RNFS.PicturesDirectoryPath}/absensi`;
    const files = await RNFS.readDir(folderPath);
    const knownFaces = [];

    for (const file of files) {
      if (file.isFile()) {
        const imageData = await fetch(`file://${file.path}`, {}, { isBinary: true }).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
        const imageTensor = decodeJpeg(new Uint8Array(imageData));

        const model = await loadFaceNetModel();
        const embeddings = model.predict(imageTensor.expandDims(0));

        knownFaces.push({
          id: file.name.split('.')[0],  // Extract the name without extension
          embeddings: embeddings
        });
      }
    }

    return knownFaces;
  };

  const compareFaces = (predictions, knownFaces) => {
    let bestMatch = null;
    let bestDistance = Infinity;

    for (const knownFace of knownFaces) {
      const distance = tf.norm(predictions.sub(knownFace.embeddings), 'euclidean').dataSync()[0];
      if (distance < bestDistance) {
        bestDistance = distance;
        bestMatch = knownFace.id;
      }
    }

    // Threshold for similarity
    if (bestDistance < 0.6) {  // You may need to adjust this threshold
      return bestMatch;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  const confirmPhoto = async () => {
    try {
      if (!capturedPhoto) {
        Alert.alert("Error", "No photo captured.");
        return;
      }

      const predictions = await detectFace(capturedPhoto);
      const knownFaces = await loadKnownFaces();
      const match = compareFaces(predictions, knownFaces);

      if (match) {
        Alert.alert("Success", `Face recognized successfully! ID: ${match}`);
      } else {
        Alert.alert("Failed", "Face not recognized.");
      }

      setShowPreview(false);
      setCapturedPhoto(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error confirming photo:', error);
      Alert.alert("Error", "Failed to confirm photo.");
    }
  };

  const retakePhoto = () => {
    setCapturedPhoto(null);
    setShowPreview(false);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        style={styles.camera}
        device={device}
        isActive={!showPreview}
        ref={camera}
        photo={true}
      />
      {showPreview ? (
        <View style={styles.previewContainer}>
          {capturedPhoto && (
            <Image
              source={{ uri: 'file://' + capturedPhoto }}
              style={styles.capturedImage}
            />
          )}
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Button title="Retake" onPress={retakePhoto} />
            <Button title="Confirm" onPress={confirmPhoto} />
          </View>
        </View>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="Take Photo" onPress={takePhoto} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  previewContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    padding: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capturedImage: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    marginBottom: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default AbsensiScreen;


I want to use the model.json of face net for face recognition based on the data that has been stored when the user registers the face by taking a selfie and display the output as an id which is the file name.

